# Убрать интерфейс у FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Делаю чат. Для отображения списка сообщений использую FlowDocument с пришаманеным биндингом. (контрол писал не я) Выглядит это вот так:

```
namespace FlowItemsControlApp.Controls
{
    public class FlowItemsControl : Control
    {
        private FlowDocument _document;

        static FlowItemsControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(FlowItemsControl), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FlowItemsControl)));
        }

        #region ItemsSource

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ItemsSource), 
            typeof(IEnumerable), 
            typeof(FlowItemsControl), 
            new PropertyMetadata(OnItemsSourceChanged));

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var flowItemsControl = (FlowItemsControl) sender;
            var newValue = (IEnumerable) e.NewValue;
            var oldValue = (IEnumerable) e.OldValue;
            flowItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged(newValue, oldValue);
        }

        private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable newValue, IEnumerable oldValue)
        {
            var notifyCollectionChanged = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (notifyCollectionChanged != null)
            {
                notifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= OnItemsChanged;
            }

            notifyCollectionChanged = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (notifyCollectionChanged != null)
            {
                notifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += OnItemsChanged;
            }

            ApplyItemsSource(newValue);
        }

        private void ApplyItemsSource(IEnumerable itemsSource)
        {
            if (_document == null)
                return;

            foreach (var newItem in itemsSource)
            {
                var newContainer = GetContainerForItem(newItem);
                if (ItemTemplate != null)
                {
                    var content = ItemTemplate.LoadContent() as Paragraph;
                    if (content != null)
                    {
                        var inlines = content.Inlines.ToList();
                        content.Inlines.Clear();
                        newContainer.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
                    }
                }
                newContainer.DataContext = newItem;
                _document.Blocks.Add(newContainer);
            }
        }

        private void OnItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_document == null)
                return;

            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        var newContainer = GetContainerForItem(newItem);
                        newContainer.DataContext = newItem;
                        _document.Blocks.Add(newContainer);
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
                    {
                        var oldContainer = _document.Blocks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DataContext == oldItem);
                        if (oldContainer == null)
                            continue;

                        _document.Blocks.Remove(oldContainer);
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    _document.Blocks.Clear();
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region ItemTemplate

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ItemTemplate), 
            typeof (DataTemplate), 
            typeof (FlowItemsControl), 
            new PropertyMetadata(OnItemTemplateChanged));

        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnItemTemplateChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var flowItemsControl = (FlowItemsControl)sender;
            var newValue = (DataTemplate)e.NewValue;
            flowItemsControl.OnItemTemplateChanged(newValue);
        }

        private void OnItemTemplateChanged(DataTemplate newValue)
        {
            if (_document == null)
                return;

            foreach (var paragraph in _document.Blocks.OfType<Paragraph>())
            {
                var content = newValue.LoadContent() as Paragraph;
                paragraph.Inlines.Clear();

                if (content != null)
                {
                    var inlines = content.Inlines.ToList();
                    content.Inlines.Clear();
                    paragraph.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            _document = Template.FindName("Document", this) as FlowDocument;
        }

        protected virtual Paragraph GetContainerForItem(object item)
        {
            return new Paragraph()
            {
                DataContext = item,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

+

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FlowItemsControlApp.Controls">

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type controls:FlowItemsControl}"
           TargetType="{x:Type controls:FlowItemsControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:FlowItemsControl}">
                    <ContentControl>
                        <FlowDocument x:Name="Document" />
                    </ContentControl>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>

<controls:FlowItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MessageVMs}" Grid.Row="1">
    <controls:FlowItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat=HH:mm}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding UserName}" Foreground="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
                <Run Text="&gt;"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </Paragraph>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:FlowItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</controls:FlowItemsControl>
```

скрин: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnt9cn0eusz58sk/screen.png?dl=0

Помогите пожалуйста убрать внизу полосу с интерфейсом от PageViewer-а. Она мне категорически не нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш

```
<FlowDocument x:Name="Document" />
```

неявно оборачивается в `FlowDocumentReader`. Попробуйте указать контейнер явно:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument x:Name="Document" />
</RichTextBox>
```

Получается то, что надо:

[image: каааз-з-лы!]